# CocoaPods - Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

I'm new to iOS, I already have `Alamofire` and `MarqueeLabel` on my `Podfile` and now trying to add `GoogleMaps`, it keeps showing this message,

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`
```

My `Podfile` looks like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Migapixel' do
    
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
    
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    
    pod 'Alamofire',
        :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
    :branch => 'master',
      :tag => '4.0.0'
    
    pod 'MarqueeLabel/Swift',
    :git => 'https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel.git'
    
    
    
  # Pods for Migapixel
  
  post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| target.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO' end end end
  
  target 'MigapixelTests' do
  
  inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MigapixelUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I even tried this

```
pod 'GoogleMaps',
    :git => 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try removing `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` and moving `use_frameworks!` out of the target block. Moreover you don't need to manually set the git path for both Alamofire and MarqueeLabel. 
Try this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Migapixel' do

    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'MarqueeLabel/Swift'


  # Pods for Migapixel
end

post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| target.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO' end end end

target 'MigapixelTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'MigapixelUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
```

Edit:

It seems that there's something wrong with your local repo. 
Try cleaning and reinstalling:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Comment: it still says [!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`

Comment: @WasifKhalil really strange. Try running this on your terminal "pod try GoogleMaps"

Comment: when i try pod update or pod try googlemaps it does this and gets stuck
pod try GoogleMaps
Updating spec repositories
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.....

Comment: i have been trying this, does it take time to finish? when i run pod setup --verbose it is showing "Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
  Cloning into 'master'..." its been 5 min, not sure if it is doing something in background or stuck

Comment: Don't worry, it takes like 10 minutes or more to finish.

Comment: This solution works for me: pod repo remove master
pod setup

Comment: pod repo remove master
pod setup
this worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

i resolved the issue like that with these step:

1. open terminal.
2. go to your project path.
3. type:

   `pod repo update`
4. install pod again.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things Here is the fix!!

**Imp:** Make sure that you have these lines in your PodFile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

If the above is fine then you need to update the pods:
try the following steps:

1. Open a new terminal and run the following command in a temp directory.

   `pod try GoogleMaps`

keep patience! It will take some time but will update the pod.

2. Now try to install the pod in ur project again. It should work.Else try to run the following commands in the project dir:

`pod repo update`

try again.
Comment in the case of any issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory and delete pods folder and .lock file then run

```
pod repo update
```

it helps for me.